# How will the following java program run, in the ""happens-before" order example?

Tags: java

Refer to the following program from the JLS.

[image: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory7.gif]

the explanation of the program is at the end of this section: 
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

i can understand that r1 will be 1, but what is the value  of r2.  Does the write of x happens-before r2's read to x makes the r2=1?

since x is not synced, it could be in local memory and r2 can be 0??   I am not clear on this about the effect of happens-before order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Happens-before Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) ( If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z) ), we have hb(x=1, y=1), hb(y=1, r1=y), hb(r1=y, r2=x), therfore hb(x=1, r2=x). So r2=1.

Comment: According to rule #1: If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

Comment: If you look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory8.gif, you can see the case where reordering can happen. If thread 2 acquires  the lock first.

Comment: I found the original rule:  If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

Comment: my question is if it runs like http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory7.gif , would x=1 and y=1 reordered? i can not find any rule that they can not reorder.    OK, it seems like even if reordered in such situation  , the result is the same . So reorder has nothing to do with "happens before"??

Comment: the following explains:    ---------------                                            It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.----------------   So it seems that the order doesn't matters.   So it mean that even in a real program run time, it could be "y=1" runs before "x=1" at run time . but such reorder doesn't change the result

Comment: more info related to this topic:  http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html