# Java, synchronization with main memory occurs only for variables in synchronize block or all instance variables?

Tags: java, synchronization, shared-memory

Consider the following toy example:

```
public class Test {

    private int nr;
    private A a;


    public synchronized A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public synchronized void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }


    public static class A{
        B b;
    }

    public static class B{
        // may contain other references
    }
}
```

Because of synchronize keyword both in get/set, we can safely read/write 'a' from multiple threads. We don't need to declare it volatile because on beginning/end of synchronize block, synchronization of local cache thread with main memory is done.

But, basically we are synchronizing on 'this', and the Test object contains also variable 'nr'. Is Java synchronization with main memory, regarding set/get 'a', occurring only for 'a', because it is the only variable accessed in those synchronized blocks, or for all members of the Test class, because we have synchronized on 'this'?

Also, when synchronization with main memory occurs, is this recursive, that is all the references chain that 'a' may contain ( 'b' in presented case ) are read/write from main memory or just 'a's reference?

Thank you

Comment: Theoretically, only a is synchronized although in practice it is very unlikely that nr won't be synchronized too.

Comment: @assylias I think that statement is incorrect. If both threads synchronize on the same object all writes to nr are guaranteed to be seen.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611109/how-will-the-following-java-program-run-in-the-happens-before-order-example `X` corresponds to `nr` and `Y` to `this.a`

Comment: @Ishtar No - imagine thread T1 and T2 and the following execution in that order from a wall clock's perspective (assuming nr is not private, otherwise it is not accessible at all): `T1: test.setA(a); test.nr = 1; T2: test.nr = 123; T1: int i = test.nr;` then T1 may read either 1 or 123. There is no happens-before relationship between `nr = 123` and `i = nr`, so even if they happen in that order from a wall clock's perpective, T1 may miss the new value.

Comment: @assylias You're right, my comment is not accurate. (It's true only if the writes go before the synchronize and the reads after and there is no intervening write). If OP means this `T1: test.nr = 1; test.setA(a); T2: test.getA(); int i = test.nr;` and there is no other write to nr it will certainly be seen, `i = 1;`

Comment: @Ishtar That is different and I agree with your conclusion in that scenario, because now there is a happens-before relationship between the write and the read to `nr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc at the [concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)

> The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write operation happens-before the read operation.
>
> ...
>
> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that monitor.

So you could say that all variables are synchronized. A bit more accurate is to say that all writes (to any variable) are seen by the reads (from the same variables) **if** the two threads `synchronized` on the same object.

If you have multiple threads A,B and C. And for example thread A and B synchronized on test1 and threads B and C synchronized on test2. Then B will see writes of A. Thread C will see writes of B and may or may not see writes of A.

Example with two threads T1 and T2, statements are executed top to bottom

```
T1             T2
test.nr = 5;   
test.setA(a1);
               test.getA(); //gives a1
               print(test.nr); //gives 5
```

With different objects:

```
T1             T2
test2.nr = 5;   
test.setA(a1);
               test.getA(); //gives a1
               print(test2.nr); //gives 5
```

Previous examples are not correctly synchronized:

```
T1             T2
               test.nr = 6;
test.nr = 5;   
test.setA(a1);
               test.getA(); //gives a1
               print(test.nr); //gives 5 or 6
```

One more example

```
T1             T2             T3
test.nr = 5;   
test.setA(a1);
               test.nr = 6;   
               test.setA(a2); 
                              test.nr = 7;
                              test.getA(); //gives a2
                              print(test.nr); //gives 5,6 or 7
```

What's in "main memory"? 5,6 or 7? Uhm, well, there is **no** main memory in the specification. So there is no right answer. A JVM will, of course, use main memory, registers and cache. But how it uses them depends on the implementation of the JVM.

One final scary example

```
T1             T2

               test.nr = 6;
               print(test.nr); //gives 5 or 6
test.nr = 5;
```

You can read the value 5, even if its not written yet!

There is a simple solution, if two threads read and/or write to the same variable, put them in a synchronized block of the same object.

Comment: Hello, I am a bit confused. I mean I know the usage of synchronize ( sequential access to a code that may be run from different threads ) but this synchronization with main memory makes me "foggy". Let's say we enter getA. I assume that 'a' will be read from main memory. But since we synchronized on 'this' will also 'nr' be read from memory (because it is an instance variable, belonging to 'this' which we've used to synchronize)?

Comment: @user3030447 There is no main memory in the JLS. So its impossible to talk about reading from main memory.. A thread will see a write if that write 'happens-before' the read (and no other write 'happens-before').

Answer (score 0):

Whatever fields that are accessed in your method is irrelevant...  only one synchronized method may be executed simultaneously.  If you want to lock on different fields, you need to synchronize manually.

For your second question, this method of synchronization is "reentrant", meaning you can recursively call the same method or any another synchronized method without fear of deadlocks.

Comment: I'm referring to http://javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_synchronized2.shtml, moreover:  "If we read and write to variables inside synchronized blocks from different threads, we do always expect Thread 1 to see the value set by Thread 2; just seeing a locally cached copy in a register isn't correct. So on entry to and exit from a synchronized block, the relevant reads/writes to main memory have to take place, and they have to take place in the correct sequence."

Comment: The specification in your link is to help guide a person when writing their own Java Virtual Machine: to make sure synchronized methods behave as per specification.  You are definitely not writing a JVM (you question is in Java, not assembly, C/C++, or something).  That specification is for the "JVM author perspective".  For the "Java programmer" perspective (you), see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6

Answer (score -1):

All `synchronized` does is to obtain a lock on the `this` object.  If one thread calls a synchronized method, then another thread tries to call a synchronized method on the same object, the second call will block until the first call is completed and releases the lock.  `synchronized` doesn't put any restrictions on how the object's fields are accessed.